# about Swift2 CoreData Updata in Xcode7

Tags: swift, core-data

I already Insert one data in CoreData.
how can i update it ?

This is my save code.

```
    @IBAction func SaveImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Content", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    let item = Content(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    if AtNearFarNmbs == 0 {
        item.photo_1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
    }else if AtNearFarNmbs == 1 {
        item.photo_2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
    }else if AtNearFarNmbs == 2{
        item.photo_3 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
    }

    do {
        try moc.save()
        print("sccess！")
    } catch {
        fatalError("the error: \(error)")
    }
    dismissVC()
```

I try to use this code want to update data.

```
    if AtNearFarNmbs == 0 {
        item?.photo_1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
    }else if AtNearFarNmbs == 1 {
        item?.photo_2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
    }else if AtNearFarNmbs == 2{
        item?.photo_3 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
    }

    do {
        try moc.save()
        print("sccess！")
    } catch {
        fatalError("the error: \(error)")
    }
```

but it not update anything.
when i check CoreData data push error is

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Fetch the object – modify its properties – save.

Comment: @Martin R can you give me something code or prompt?

Comment: This is a really bad question.  What exactly are you trying to update?  What have you tried?  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Jody Hagins sorry i editing it..

Comment: Look up `NSFetchRequest` in Apple's documentation, and `NSPredicate` while you're at it.